# Is there a secure way to validate JSON input with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, security, json, validation

I am pulling some external JSON data from a Windows 7 Gadget, which is basically a piece of JavaScript running under Internet Explorer with high security priviledges. Because of that, I want to make sure the JSON is properly formatted and isn't malicious.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: As long as you don't attempt to execute anything during validation it should be fine. Don't use code execution to test for validity (i.e. if it runs, it's valid; otherwise no).

Comment: just use json2.js http://www.json.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse(jsonString);`. This will build arrays and objects but not run any code in the JSON. To support older browsers without the HTML5 JSON object, use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) which provides the same protection using the same API by checking for invalid data before `eval()`ing the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is JavaScript. Therefore, you can validate JSON statically in the same way you would validate JavaScript. You are concerned about the `eval` approach that can usually be used to validate JavaScript, and you are being very wise to avoid this approach. If it's malicious and you execute to validate, well you're already screwed. [JSLint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint) is a great tool for this. See Stack Overflow question *[Is JSLint available for offline use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836449/is-js-lint-available-for-offline-use)* for how to utilize this utility "offline".

Another approach is to use [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). This method does correctly parse JSON containing 
functions, so be aware of this caveat.